# How to do preprocessing for zero inflated variable in multiple regression?

Tags: multiple-regression, data-transformation, zero-inflation

I am trying to build a multiple regression model, and many of my variables looks like this (histogram for time spent in the system).

[image]

The reason I had such data is because zero is actually represents another business case: customer created the account but never used it.

How should I user this types of the variables in a regression model? I have some ideas to do the preprocessing, are they valid? what else can we do?

- Idea 1, replace zero with median value of non-zero ones.
- Idea 2, create another indicator column on zero values, then replace zero with median value of non-zero ones.

Comment: Why are you imputing zero values with medians when there is clearly non-ignorable missingness? Is the goal to estimate the time they *would* have been in the system had they remained there? If you can replace the zero with a sensible censoring time, like last-login or record modification time, you might estimate a good probability model.

Comment: @AdamO thanks for the comment. I understand the problem of replace them with median but not the second point. San you tell me more about "replace the zero with a sensible censoring time, like last-login or record modification time"?

Comment: Idea 2 is correct. Idea 1 is not. On a somewhat similar note, in case you missed it the thread "[Time spent in an activity as an independent variable](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56306)" is extremely related to your question. (To the point I would assume they could be potentially merged.)

Answer (score 4):

To take these zeroes and convert them to the median would create a false sense of certainty that would bias your results.  I would assume that if these customers had nonzero values, the values would take on a range.  That's one reason why multiple imputation has become so popular:  it preserves some uncertainty, variability, in the imputed values while using all available information to assign them as plausibly as possible.  So rather than proceeding as you suggest, I would use multiple imputation as one approach.

A second approach would be censored regression, as described in the growing number of threads that you can find via a Google search or a search on this site.  I found [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49443/how-to-model-this-odd-shaped-distribution-almost-a-reverse-j/49456#49456) helpful.  (Though it may be less helpful if all your zero-inflated variables are predictors.)

In either case I like your idea of including a binary column to indicate zero/nonzero.

EDIT:  for some good introductions to multiple imputation, see the articles by Melissa Azur et al. (2011); John W. Graham (2009); and Jeffrey C. Wayman (2003).

Comment: +1. The link you provided is really helpful. I searched for zero inflated topics but did not see that page!

Comment: Can you also give me some resources for multiple imputation?

Comment: Can you edit your post to include links to the papers, or at least also the journals in which they appeared? Thank you!