# How do you deal with “nested” variables in a regression model? in R

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model, linear-model, nested-models

A conceptual solution for this scenario has been posted in:

[How do you deal with "nested" variables in a regression model?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/372257/how-do-you-deal-with-nested-variables-in-a-regression-model#comment727111_372257)

Problem is I am having trouble using this solution in R - glm() or lm().

I am using the model:

```
y ~ x1 + x1:x2
```

Unfortunately if I encode the unmeaninful/missing data as NA the default na.action removes the rows with NAs and leaves x1 with only one level - making the model equivalent to just:

```
y ~ x2
```

If I use argument to glm:

```
na.action = na.pass
```

I get an error:

*Error in glm.fit(x = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, : NA/NaN/Inf in 'x'*

If instead I encode the missing variable as 0, the nested model:

```
y ~ x1 + x1:x2
```

Gives the exact same output as the non nested model:

```
y ~ x1 + x2
```

Here is my short script exploring this:

```
y = rnorm(100, 100, 10)
x1 = sample(c(0, 1), 100, rep=T)
x2 = sample(100:200, 100, rep=T)
x2[x1 == 0] = NA # when x1 is 0 x2 is NA
df = data.frame(y, x1, x2)

nest_NA = glm(y ~ x1 + x1:x2, data=df) # NAs removed 
add_NA = glm(y ~ x1 + x2,, data=df)

nest_NA = glm(y ~ x1 + x1:x2, data=df, na.action = na.pass) # NAs allowed = error
add_NA = glm(y ~ x1 + x2,, data=df, na.action = na.pass)

x2[x1 == 0] = 0 # when x1 is 0 x2 is also 0
df = data.frame(y, x1, x2)

nest_zero = glm(y ~ x1 + x1:x2, data=df)
add_zero = glm(y ~ x1 + x2, data=df)
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that if you multiply `NA` by `0` you get `NA` instead of `0`.  Under the default options in `R`, when you run your `glm` it forms a model matrix by multiplying the elements, leading to many `NA` values through this multiplication, and then it removes all the rows with `NA` values.

What we need to do is to form the design matrix so that in the `x1:x2` term we get a zero term when we have `0:NA` (instead of this term being set to `NA` and then removed).  As you correctly point out in your question, this can be done by changing the data-frame `df` to replace the `NA` values by zeros.  However, you may prefer not to alter the raw data, and instead form the design matrix for the model directly.

```
#Form design matrix for your GLM
options(na.action = 'na.pass');
MAT    <- model.matrix( ~ 1 + x1 + x1:x2, data = df);
MAT[is.na(MAT[, 3]), 3] <- 0;

#Fit your GLM
MODEL <- glm(y ~ MAT, data = df);
summary(MODEL);

Call:
glm(formula = y ~ MAT, data = df)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-25.497   -7.363    1.093    6.944   22.913  

Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)    102.32290    1.42498  71.807   <2e-16 ***
MAT(Intercept)        NA         NA      NA       NA    
MATx1           -0.45977    7.35367  -0.063    0.950    
MATx1:x2        -0.02592    0.04761  -0.544    0.587    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 103.5589)

    Null deviance: 10540  on 99  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 10045  on 97  degrees of freedom
AIC: 752.76

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 2
```

Comment: The problem remains that when you replace the NAs with zeros the model y ~ x1 + x1:x2 gives the exact same output as y ~ x1 + x2. Therefore it is not a nested model.

Comment: I think the problem is that they are the same thing but I am expecting something different. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @Ben I'm also running into the same issue, and I agree with Adam's assessment that the model y ~ x1 + x1:x2 you are suggesting is equivalent to y ~ x1 + x2, i.e. (and please correct me if I'm wrong) the model treats the 0's actually as 0's, and not missing data. Do you have any suggestions on other approaches?

Comment: @AdamWaring: The issue here is that the data has been formed in a particular way where ```x2 = NA``` if and only if ```x1 = 0```.  That means that the explanatory term ```is.na(x2)``` is equivalent to ```x1``` in the model matrix and so it is redundant in the model; consequently, it is not included in the above answer.  You are right that the model reduces to ```y ~ x1 + x2``` in this case, but that is a peculiarity of the fact that occurrence of nesting is already indicated perfectly by the binary model term ```x1```.

Comment: @Ben Thanks for responding so quickly. I agree that there's a singularity, but is there no way around it? Surely there must be a way to encode the model such that all meaningless values of X2 are not interpreted by the model as actual values?

Comment: @platypus17: You don't need a way around it in this case since the missingness indicator is already ```x1```.  In more general cases, you would add the model term ```(x2 == 0)``` as the missingness indicator.